# error when install google chrome on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, selenium

When I tried to install google chrome on ubuntu, I get the following error: when I do `google-chrome -v`

```
[3880:3880:1012/130454:ERROR:desktop_window_tree_host_x11.cc(904)] Not implemented reached in virtual void views::DesktopWindowTreeHostX11::InitModalType(ui::ModalType)
```

I'm following the instrunctions here
https://christopher.su/2015/selenium-chromedriver-ubuntu/

any idea on how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be running this as root, is that the case? I receive the same error if I run `google-chrome -v` as root:

```
┌─[root@Fedora]─[~]─[12:59 pm]
└─[$]› google-chrome -v
[1908:1908:1013/125639:ERROR:desktop_window_tree_host_x11.cc(904)] Not implemented reached in virtual void views::DesktopWindowTreeHostX11::InitModalType(ui::ModalType)
```

If so, try running as a standard user. It opens as expected for me.